# Changing ELB URL pattern

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, hosting, amazon-elb

I have website which hosted in AWS cloud which have a pattern like below:

dev-648525573.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com/App1/

Above url is an ELB url. ELB is hosted with two EC2 instances both have same website which is hosted in IIS.

Initially the site was hosted under default website, under App1 folder.

But now the site is moved out of default website to its parent "site" folder.

Hence when i type www.localhost in the ec3 browser, i can see the website i dont need to use www.localhost\app1 (i moved the site out of app1 folder)

My problem is still ELB url not taking the changed path

Ideally the site should come when i hit:

dev-648525573.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com/

but its not happening.

What change i need to do to make it work?

Comment: This is a configuration on the IIS side, as Elastic Load Balancing doesn't handle paths and just forwards requests to the backend. Have you checked your server's virtual path configuration?

Comment: where i check servers virtual path?

Comment: You can check IIS configuration by going onto the machine and launching the "IIS Manager". This might [be useful](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763173.aspx).